# C99 warning for assigning a void pointer to a non-void pointer?

Tags: c, standards, c99, void-pointers

In my C99 standard document (actually a free committee draft from September 2007), Annex I Common Warnings 2, it states that

`(when) an implicit narrowing conversion is encountered, such as the assignment of a long int or a double to an int, or a pointer to void to a pointer to any type other than a character type (6.3)`

is one of a few of the more common situations where an implementation may generate a warning.

Well, then shouldn't it be likely that a c compiler spits a warning to code such as `int *p = malloc(sizeof(*p))`? While it seems more common in C code not to cast `malloc`s.

Comment: "May generate" may mean that if the compiler knows that no information is lost, it won't warn? For example, if you assign the result of `malloc` to an inappropriate near pointer on a segmented architecture you'd get a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `C99 Annex I`, where the quote comes from:

> An implementation may generate warnings in many situations, none of which are specified as part of this International Standard. The following are a few of the more common situations.

The operative phrase here is "may generate". Standards language is very precise. If they wanted to insist a warning was generated, they would have used the phrase "shall generate" or "must generate".

It's likely that, if your environment was one where accessing invalidly-aligned data types (such as a word on a non-word boundary) would result in catastrophic failure (like a bus error), the compiler would warn you of such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

No, it shouldn't generate a warning when assigning `void*` to another pointer, since this is exactly what the construct `void*` is invented for. This is a generic pointer that can be converted to any other data pointer. This is by no means comparable to a narrowing conversion of integer types, where you might have a loss of information. Here nothing is lost.

Besides I find that narrowing warning business that comes now abundant in C++ with C++ compilers switching to C++11 very annoying. At least in C a narrowing conversion to an unsigned integer type is very precisely defined and the compiler shouldn't bark.